# How to recall the attributes of the specific agents that are stored in a collection in Anylogic 8.7?

Tags: java, anylogic

I am creating an agent based model in Anylogic 8.7. I have a population of agents where they have attributes linked to an excel file as parameters meaning each row of the excel table represents an agent.
I will break my case down as follows:
There are some agents that share the same attribute value in one parameter called `track`. So I wanted to filter them and select each one and do some mathematical actions on each of the agents.
I created a collection with `ArrayList class` and `Agent elements` using this code to seperate the agents:

`collection.addAll(findAll(population,p -> p.track==Tracknum)`

//`Tracknum` is a variable and `track` is a parameter representing  the agent attributes.

The given collection will seperate them in its Array but what I do not know is how to retrieve each one of the listed agents from the collection and get another one of their attributes to do some mathematical work. I would be grateful if you help me through this process. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Loop across the ArrayList like with standard Java.

```
for (AgentyType currentAgent : collection ) {
    // access every agent in collection here, example:
    traceln(currentAgent.track);
}
```

Alternatively, google Java Streams to learn how to do it with less code

Comment: Thank you for your response Benjamin. Is there a way to retrieve those values from the console one by one? And there is an iteration going on which fills up the list in the given collection over time.on every step I want to clear the collection so a new set of data would be stored in it. Is this mechanism also possible? Thank you.